# Sharing google sheet with service account when 'Sharing outside of organization is OFF'

Tags: sharing, gspread, google-workspace

I'm using [GSpread](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to download data from Google sheets and store them in a Postgres DB for different organisations.

Unfortunately one organisation has activated G Suite's strict sharing setting which makes it impossible for users to share documents outside their organisation.

This affects my ability to share Google sheets in this organisation with service accounts which are required for GSpread.

Note: I created the service account within the respective organisation and also already [delegated domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount?hl=de#delegatingauthority) to the service account.

Any idea on how to share the Google sheet with the account?